# flash only accepts multiple characters in input box

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm trying to capture 1 letter in the text box, but flash only registers when I type in multiple letters, so if I type 'G' it doesn't work but if I type 'GH' then it registers.
I'm capturing it like this so far. (partial code)

```
function goToFrame8(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    addChild(answerInput);
    answerInput.x = 350;
    answerInput.y = 350;


    //next 'frame' button
    addChild(next8);
    next8.x = 650;
    next8.y = 520;
    next8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToFrame9);


    answerInput.randomText.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, inputEventCapture);
}


function inputEventCapture(event:TextEvent):void
{
    text1 = answerInput.randomText.text;
}

function goToFrame9(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(text1);
removeChild(answerInput);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP` event instead of `TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT`. The KEY_UP event fires after a key has been pressed then released. The object you add the event listener to will need focus but your textfield will have focus because you have to click the textfield to type into it.

```
function goToFrame8(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    addChild(answerInput);
    answerInput.x = 350;
    answerInput.y = 350;


    //next 'frame' button
    addChild(next8);
    next8.x = 650;
    next8.y = 520;
    next8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToFrame9);


    answerInput.randomText.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, inputEventCapture);
}


function inputEventCapture(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    text1 = answerInput.randomText.text;
}

function goToFrame9(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(text1);
    removeChild(answerInput);
}
```

Comment: sweet Jonny Henly. Thanks!

Comment: To add to this, you can use `Event.CHANGE` as well. Event.CHANGE will fire on mobile devices after every character change whereas `KeyboardEvent`s will only fire after the soft keyboard is hidden.